# AWS SES, sending mail with an unverified 'from'

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm trying to create a discussion list sender using SES. The 'receive' part is fine, but when I send, I want to preserve the user's "from" address. Aside from some subject rewriting, here's what I'm doing to the headers; VERIFIED_FROM is my mailing list alias. This is py3.6, but it shouldn't matter.

```
msg['Reply-To'] = VERIFIED_FROM_EMAIL
msg['Return-Path'] = VERIFIED_FROM_EMAIL
```

When I call `sendRawEmail`, I get an error like this, brackets for scrubbed entries:

> [ERROR]   [timestamp] [request id] Client error while forwarding email for <[VERIFIED_FROM_EMAIL]> to <[all emails on list]>: An error occurred (MessageRejected) when calling the SendRawEmail operation: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: ["user who sent the message" user@domain.com]

I can't put all users on the verified list. I could set the 'from' to my list address, but then I lose the identity of the sender.

I'm sure this has been done with SES- but how?

Answer (score 1):

The `reply-to` field and the `return-path` field are fields that require a validated email address. [1]

With each email you relay, you can create a unique email address for people to reply to (e.g. abcdef123@yourdomain.com) which you can then relay back to the same threads using the `Message-ID` and `In-Reply-To` headers.

You can also modify what the name looks like for the message using the `Name <email@yourdomain.com>` header too.

[1] https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=221703